# Ember-data removeObject on a hasMany relationship also removes the child entry from Ember's Store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    phoneNumber: DS.attr('string'),
    studies: DS.hasMany('study', {async: true})
});

App.Study = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

I want to un-assign some `Studies` from a `User`.
When the user presses the un-assign button in the view, there is an action inside the controller which runs this code:

```
actions: {
 //...
 unassign: function(study){
     this.get('user').get('studies').removeObject(study);
     this.get('user').save();
 }
 //...
}
```

This removes the `studyId` from the `users.studies` list, but it also removes that `study` completely from Ember's store.

How can I just un-assign the `study` from the `user.studies` , but keep the `studies` table unaffected.

I'm using:

```
Ember VERSION = '1.5.1';
Ember-Data Version = 1.0.0-beta.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I overcome the problem by computing the list of studies and setting it. (NOT CALLING removeObject). Something among the lines:

```
actions: {

  unassing: function() {
    var newUserStudies = Ember.A();
    this.get('studies').forEach(function(study) {
       if (study.get('selected')) { //selected
          newUserStudies.push(study);
       } 
    });
    this.get('user').set('studies', newUserStudies);
    this.get('user').save();
  }
}
```